# get inputString with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am changing this code I have to jquery, and I want to get the inputString. how is this done with jquery. I imagine I should use .val() , but I cant see where it would fit in. Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#email").keyup(function() {

      if(inputString.length == 0) {
         //do something

      }
   });
});

     <input type = "text" id = "email">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides you may use `$(this).val()` but the following way is faster:

```
$("#email").keyup(function() {
    var inputString = this.value;
    // ...
});
```